# Convert all values in an excel column into a formatted url

Tags: excel, formulas

I have a column in an excel spreadsheet which contains product descriptions in multiple languages.

Currently im having to copy and paste them into google translate to figure out what the are.

I was hoping i could automatically add a new column to my document and convert all values from another column into a URL.

my URL format is `https://translate.google.cn/?hl=en#auto/en/{0}`
where {0} is replaced by the text to translate. This URL will automatically attempt to convert text into English. I can then just click on the cell which will open the browser with my translation.

Any idea what formula best serves this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `HYPERLINK` function, see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US, like so:

[image]

Formula in `B2` downwards:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://translate.google.cn/?hl=en#auto/en/"&A2)
```

`"https://translate.google.cn/?hl=en#auto/en/"&A2` is a concatenation of the given string "https://translate.google.cn/?hl=en#auto/en/" with the content of `A2`.